# I can't access this variable outside the function that will be used for database connection

Tags: python, function, mysql-python

I am trying to access cursor outside the function dbconnect(). But I am getting this error "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'"

It would be really great if somebody could fix it. I am trying to make a program for school project. Code is given below.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

def dbconnect():
    db = mysql.connect(host='',
                       database='',
                       user='',
                       password='')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor


query = "select name,atomic_weight from elements where atomic_number = 8"
dbconnect.cursor.execute(query)
result = dbconnect.cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Comment: What about `cursor = dbconnect(); cursor.execute(query)`?

Comment: it gives error: ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Comment: Can you please add the full code that produces this error?

Comment: import mysql.connector as mysql

def dbconnect():
    db = mysql.connect(host='',
                       database='',
                       user='',
                       password='')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor


cursor = dbconnect()
query = "select name,atomic_weight from elements where atomic_number = 8"
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = dbconnect()
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```